# Kivy animation works slowly

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

In my kivy app I have a `ScreenManager` with 2 Screen objects.

```
class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='firstscreen'))
        root.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='secondscreen'))
        return root
```

At the `SecondScreen` there is a `MyLayout(GridLayout)` object with `AsyncImage` objects. And I use `Anmation` to move this layout.

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.children[0].minimum_width > self.width:
           anim = Animation(x=(self.right - self.children[0].minimum_width), duration=10 * (self.children[0].minimum_width / self.width))
           anim.start(self.children[0])
```

And I have a problem: when there are too many `AsyncImage` objects, animation works slowly, with low FPS.

There is also my .kv:

```
<FirstScreen>:
    Button:
        text: '2 screen'
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'secondscreen'

<SecondScreen>:
    MyLayout:
        MyImage
        MyImage
        ...
```

How can I fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `self.children[0]`? If it's anything other than a RelativeLayout, try using a RelativeLayout here (you can put everything else inside it). RelativeLayout's translation is far more optimised than that of most widgets, and is intended for situations like this.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to animate `Screen` widget, and it works much beter.

Comment: You may want to read [mcve].

Comment: @inclement Can you post that as an answer?